# How to create DisplayAlert with TextFields in XamarinForms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I want to create DiaplayAlert from the ViewModel where I have text fields to enter information. At the moment I can create simple DisplayAlerts, await `App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Error message", "OK");` but I want to be able to add more things, checks button, textfields, labels, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, no. You need to implement custom renderer for show dialogs for each platform.

Try to use this plugin: [rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)